# Daisy chain from usb c to display port 1.2 from first monitor

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, thunderbolt, usb-c, daisychaining

I'm planning to purchase **LG 32UL950-W** monitor. It supports 4k Daisy chaining with Thunderbolt 3. At the moment I'm using **Lenovo T23i-10** monitor which comes with ***Display port 1.2***. I use USB-C to Display port 1.2 cable to drive this monitor through my MacBook Pro 2019.

Now, lets say if I purchase **LG 32UL950-W**, would I be able to drive second **Lenovo T23i-10** monitor through daisy chaining feature using ***USB-C to Display port 1.2 cable***?

Comment: From what I understand, though am not an expert, MacOS does not support daisy chaining monitors.